# MPI, Fortran, multitasking

Tags: fortran, mpi, multitasking

I would like to perform many independent operations (e.g. time integration of an ODE with different initial conditions) using MPI and Fortran. The initial conditions are a 2$\times 1000$ vector IC for example.

```
do i=1,1000
   (x0,y0) = (x(i),y(i))
   Solve an ODE with (x0,y0) for a time duration
   Save the result at the end of this duration
enddo
```

Can anyone help with a minimal code using MPI or a link to something similar.

I have already used OMP but I think with MPI I would have access to more CPUs

Comment: There are tons of tutorials for MPI on the web: have you searched? have you read some of them? have some tried something? If yes can you show what you have tried?

Comment: If you are running on a cluster it may be easier to write a batch script that spawns all of the ensemble, rather than getting involved in MPI which is really for the case where you want to solve one problem with multiple processes.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. I also suggest reading [ask]. To me, your question is too broad for this site. Or actually is not even an actual question but a request for some code. I agree with Ian that if your jobs are independent, it can be solved by launching independent processes in batch.

Comment: I missed the word "independent"... and agree with @IanBush: using MPI (which is nowhere as simple as OpenMP) for independent operations is a kind of hammer to kill a fly...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the operations are truly independent (and the number of cases is a multiple of the number of processors) then:

- call mpi_scatter to distribute start points from root
- call
- call mpi_gather to collect the results back on root

root can then write to file.

If the number of processors doesn't divide into the number of cases then you can use mpi_scatterv and mpi_gatherv instead.

Example (rather trivial work per job, rather than solving ODEs):

```
program main
   use iso_fortran_env
   use mpi
   implicit none

   integer stat(mpi_status_size), tag, ierr
   integer size, rank
   integer, parameter :: N = 256 * 1000          ! assumes this is a multiple of the number of processors
   integer, parameter :: root = 0
   integer myN
   integer i
   real(real64), allocatable :: Y(:), myY(:)
   real(real64) start, finish


   call mpi_init( ierr )
   call mpi_comm_size( mpi_comm_world, size, ierr )
   call mpi_comm_rank( mpi_comm_world, rank, ierr )

   ! Set initial values for full array, then start timing
   if ( rank == root ) then
      allocate( Y(N) )
      Y = [ ( i + 0.0_real64, i = 1, N ) ]

      start = gettime()
   end if

   ! Root parcels out the work (i.e., distributes the starting points)
   ! Processor with rank r will look at indices 1+r*N/size to (r+1)*N/size
   myN = N / size
   allocate( myY(myN) )
   call mpi_scatter(   Y, myN, mpi_double_precision,                            &
                     myY, myN, mpi_double_precision, root, mpi_comm_world, ierr )

   ! Each processor does its own work
   call myWork( myN, myY )
   
   ! Root gets its results back
   call mpi_gather ( myY, myN, mpi_double_precision,                            &
                       Y, myN, mpi_double_precision, root, mpi_comm_world, ierr )

   ! Root concludes timing, then writes to file
   if ( rank == root ) then
      finish = gettime()
      write( *, * ) "Time taken = ", finish - start

      open( 10, file="output.txt" )
      write( 10, "( i8, 1x, es11.4 )" ) ( i, Y(i), i = 1, N )
      close( 10 )

      deallocate( Y )
   end if
  
   deallocate( myY )

   call mpi_finalize( ierr )


contains

   subroutine myWork( N, Y )
      integer     , intent(in   ) :: N
      real(real64), intent(inout) :: Y(N)
      integer i

      do i = 1, 10000
         Y = 2 * Y - Y   ! silly example, just to use some flops
      end do
   end subroutine myWork


   real(real64) function getTime()
      integer t(8)
      call date_and_time( values=t )
      getTime = 3600 * t(5) + 60 * t(6) + t(7) + 0.001 * t(8)
   end function getTime

end program main
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but probably not required for the question asked.  OP's needs would seem to be more easily satisfied by a batch script.